# Fix the background image when menu has selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, themes

I am using Indexu-deluxe and I have uploaded costume theme on my site.Following is my sites URL.
http://www.submitweb.us/

when you over the mouse on any menu the background image  appears and when you have mouse out, the image disappears.

Now I want to do that By default the background image shows at home menu and when i have selected or clicked on another menu it will show on that menu.

please help me for this.

Comment: you have to do it by back end its not java script game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can make a class called `.active` which have a `background-image` set to your image.

You can apply this class directly to the selected menu 
 **OR** 
you can give each menu an ID, for example `#powersearch` for power search page menu (li), and apply this script on each page for the selected menu :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#powerSearch').addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have a different page for each section right?
Like one for home, one for power search?